# Run command from sudo su

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, su

On a machine I (tlous) have been given access to open a shell as another user (serviceAccount)

Executing: `sudo su - serviceAccount` has the desired effect of opening a shell as this serviceAccount user. So far so good.

This is nice, but I want to run a command as this user without opening a shell.

Let's say the command is `whoami`

I've tried:

`sudo -u serviceAccount whoami`

Sorry, user tlous is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/whoami' as serviceAccount ...

`sudo su - serviceAccount -c whoami`

Sorry, user tlous is not allowed to execute `'/bin/su - serviceAccount -c whoami'` ...

And other variations. What am I missing? Can this be done in a oneliner? The reason is that I actually want to run this as an ssh command: `ssh -t tlous@server.example.com sudo su - serviceAccount -c whoami`

**Update 20190412 with sudo -l**

`sudo -l`

```
Matching Defaults entries for tlous on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY
    LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, !authenticate

User tlous may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) /usr/bin/su - serviceAccount, /bin/su - serviceAccount
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` to the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output from `sudo -l`, to wit:

```
User tlous may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) /usr/bin/su - serviceAccount, /bin/su - serviceAccount
```

You are given *explicit* rights in the `sudoers` configuration to run two specific commands:

- `/usr/bin/su - serviceAccount`
- `/bin/su - serviceAccount`

Adding more parameters, as you're trying (e. g. `sudo -u serviceAccount whoami`) is not on the approved command list.

You will need to request that your system administrator add to the `sudoers` configuration the other commands you desire access to run via `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this:

ssh -t tlous@server.example.com "sudo -u serviceAccount whoami"

Comment: Already tried that (see first below `I've tried`)

Comment: Edit sudoers file and allow user serviceAccount to execute that command

Comment: If I could do that I wouldn't have this issue in the first place :-)

Comment: Maybe you can try this instead:   ssh -t tlous@server.example.com "sudo su -c whoami serviceAccount"

Comment: I have tried what you are trying on my VM and it seems to work fine. What OS are you on?